# Berkshelf hangs at supermarket.chef.io after adding local cookbook path to berksfile

Tags: chef-infra, berkshelf

Berks install works perfectly until I specify local path to a cookbook. I am not able to stop the process, it will hang indefinitely.

My versions:

```
pkud$ chef --version
Chef Development Kit Version: 0.9.0
chef-client version: 11.18.12
berks version: 4.0.1
kitchen version: 1.4.2
```

Berksfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
source "https://supermarket.chef.io"

# GitHub Cookbooks
cookbook 'android-sdk',     :github => 'gildegoma/chef-android-sdk'
cookbook 'cassandra-dse',   :github => 'michaelklishin/cassandra-chef-cookbook'
cookbook 'users',           :github => 'opscode-cookbooks/users', :ref => 'refs/tags/v1.8.0'
cookbook 'kafka',           :github => 'hw-cookbooks/kafka'

cookbook 'auth', path:  '/Users/pkud/Projects/services/chef/auth'

# API Cookbooks
cookbook 'apt'
cookbook 'certificate'
cookbook 'consul'
cookbook 'elasticsearch', '~>0.3.14'
cookbook 'grafana', '~> 2.1.3'
cookbook 'graphite'
cookbook 'java'
cookbook 'memcached'
cookbook 'mongodb'
cookbook 'redisio'
cookbook 'route53'
cookbook 'varnish', '= 1.0.2'
cookbook 'apache_zookeeper'
cookbook 'rbenv'
```

Berks install output:

```
Fetching 'auth' from source at ../auth
Fetching cookbook index from https://supermarket.chef.io...
```

Berks install debug output:

```
D, [2015-10-29T17:55:44.982518 #21892] DEBUG -- :   Adding explicit dependency on auth (0.1.0) '/Users/pkud/Projects/services/chef/auth'
D, [2015-10-29T17:55:44.982677 #21892] DEBUG -- :   Starting resolution...
```

and it never resolves...

Comment: What are the dependencies of your auth cookbook ?

Comment: An minimal example posted on GitHub in a repo or Gist might be the best way to help us reproduce, to help you.